# How to add session id to swift php mysql application backend

Tags: php, session, token

I am currently developing a back-end for an `iOS` application with `Apache`, `PHP` and `MySQL`. However, I am a bit lost now that I have to implement an authentication method into the application.

- Whenever a user signs up to the application, a unique user id is issued and saved in the database.
- Then, when the user logs in I add the unique user id to the `$_SESSIONS["Id"]`.
- In addition, when the user logs out, the session is destroyed.

However, I find it unclear on how this can help me implement an authentication method without having to log in the user again and again.

So, after logging in and the app needs other information from the database, should I pass the unique `userId` to the PHP script to check if it's the same as the `$_SESSION["Id"]`?

Comment: do apps have anything at all by session data? is it for browser's , isn't it?

Comment: Is this question for the swift (client) side or for the php (server) side? Please tag only the platform that the question applies.

Comment: Swift is used for the client side and php for the server side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry, but I don't understand what you are asking.

If you set `$_SESSION["Id"]` on login and destroy it on logout, then that should be sufficient.

The first line of your db script should just read

```
if (isset($_SESSION["Id"]) {
    // do stuff knowing the user is authenticated
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I understand the session part, however, how will this cope with multiple users requesting from the same server at the same time?

Comment: Multiple users will not affect each other.  This is exactly what the session manager does - keep everyone's information secure and separate from each other. Try adding a var_export($_SESSION['Id']) and load the page from 2 different computers at the same time.  You will see that the data is not shared.  :)

Comment: Ok. So when the user signs up to the ios app, a random UserId is created for that user and saved. This is added as the $_SESSION["Id"]. So, when the app asks for another request such as retrieve data from a database, do I first check if there is a $_SESSION["Id']? Will this separate the data from different users? Sorry for being so lost

Comment: Yes, you are correct.  Where I said '// do stuff' , this is where you can query your database for user id = $_SESSION["Id"].  This will only return results for your current user

Comment: Also, you mentioned 'random UserId' .  random ids are bound to repeat eventually. I hope you are generating IDs sequentially, in order.   Post a different question if you have doubts about that